# Install large android application directly on SD card

Tags: android, eclipse, size, sd-card

I am developing an application and because of the images is very heavy (around 25Mb).
The problem is that I have not enough space in the phone memory to install it, but of course I have a lot of free space on the SD card.

I tried already with:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

but it keeps saying me that I don't have enough space on disk and eclipse sends me an error.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying this with a device connected to eclipse or using an emulator? Either way, what is the Android version of the device/emulator? If it's less than v2.2 then it's not possible to install an app onto external storage so it will always fallback to attempting to install on the device (or emulator) internal memory.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using eclipse to install the app. The version I have is 2.2, so it should work!

Comment: But is this a physical device or an emulator? If it's a physical device connected by USB, make sure the SD card hasn't been dismounted as part of the connection. If it's an emulator then make sure you have plenty of 'emulated' space for your 'emulated' SD card.

Comment: It it a physical device. I couldn't do it so the solution I've used is just copy the large files to the sd card so the program itself is not that heavy.

Answer (score 4):

A good workaround is to trim down the APK and download the images upon first run, saving them directly to the sd card. You can provide in the APK low-res images to show while downloading the hi-res ones, if needed.